# comapring with boolean using triple equals for result set of mysql query

Tags: php, mysqli

Why we are using triple equals here to compare ?

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
}
```

Comment: [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: @mario
My question is clearly different , I am asking in another sense that why we are using triple equals for comparing with boolean but the other question only asks the difference between =,== and ===. Please try to read the question before marking it duplicate.

Comment: I fail to see the uniqueness of your question. The [difference between `==` and `===`](https://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+php+difference+between+%3D%3D+and+%3D%3D%3D+equals) comes up every other week. And it's *also* answered by the linked answers. If you want to differentiate yours from prior questions, just write a less coarse question.

Comment: @mario I did not know that `$conn->query($sql)` can return true , false and object . If I did not ask it I how would I know it ? At least now I know about it , the other questions with whom you are matching my question , they are asking about the differences of =,== and === and I know it .
Now you even can delete the question , go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many PHP functions may return mixed types, unlike many other languages. If you would compare with `==`, only values would be tested. Therefore any non-zero value would be equal to true, and also things like `123 == '123abc'` would be true.

The `===` operator requires types to be the same also, so any object is not equal to true and even `123 === '123'` doesn't equal true.